# Binding a GridView to an ObservableCollection in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview, datasource, observablecollection

I am developing my first ASP.Net Web Application, I am learning a lot, but I have a problem that I can't figure out.

I have a GridView  with a Collection as DataSource, if I bind the GridView to the Collection it works fine:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("hello");
l.Add("world");

GridView1.DataSource = l;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But the problem is that when I add a new item to the list it does not show in the Grid, I have read that it's normal, that changes after doing the GridView1.DataBind(); are not added to the Grid.

I have done some research and I found that I can use ObservableCollection to do it, if you bind an ObservableCollection to a GridView and you add a new item, the change should happen in also in the GridView. I have done this:

```
ObservableCollection<string> o = new ObservableCollection<string>();
o.Add("hello");
o.Add("world");

GridView1.DataSource = o;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

And when I run the app it works fine, the data is displayed, but I added a button, and in the click event, I add a new element to the ObservableCollection, but it does not appear in the Grid, and I don't know why.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     o.Add("test");
}
```

Hope somebody can help me with that.

Thanks!!